# Simulating a particular plot from a paper

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the following equation :

\begin{equation}
\Delta = \alpha \left[n\left(\mu+\frac{\Delta}{2}\right)-n\left(\mu-\frac{\Delta}{2}\right)\right]
\end{equation}
over a list of parameter values of $\mu$ and where $n(x)$ is defined as
$$
n(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  g(\epsilon) f(\epsilon-x)d\epsilon
$$
and the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are respectively,
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{\exp(x/T)+1}& T\ne0 \\ \Theta(-x) & T = 0\end{cases}\qquad g(x) = \frac{1}{w\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/w^2}
$$
where $T$ is an array of values and $w$ is a fixed constant.

The color plot of $\Delta$ as a function of $T$ and $V_{g}$($\mu$ scales with $V_{g}$ and for all intensive purposes we can treat the plot as a density plot for $(T,\mu)$) is supposed to look like :[image]

where $V_g$ scales similar to $\mu$.

I wanted to do this calculation in Mathematica and have the following code :
In this code I create and array of $\mu$ and `T` values, and solve the equation for $\Delta$ (`x` below is $\Delta$)

```
w = 0.42; alph = 2.1;

g[e_, w_] := (1/(w Sqrt[2 π])) Exp[-e^2/w^2/2] 

fermi[μ_, e_, T_] := If[T == 0, If[e < μ, 1, 0], 1/(Exp[(e - μ)/T] + 1)]

Tmin = 0 ; Tmax = 0.7 ; NT = 10 ; muMin = 0 ; muMax = 0.6  ; Nmu = 15 ;

T[i_] := Tmin + (i - 1)/NT (Tmax - Tmin) ; 
Mu[i_] := muMin + (i - 1) /Nmu (muMax - muMin) ; 

gap1[x_?NumericQ, μ_, T_] := 
  Abs[x - alph (
    NIntegrate[fermi[μ + x/2, e, T] g[e, w], {e, -Infinity, Infinity}]
      - NIntegrate[fermi[μ - x/2, e, T] g[e, w], {e, -Infinity, Infinity}]
    )]

gapSol = 
  Table[Table[
    FindRoot[gap1[x, Mu[i], T[j]] == 0, {x, 2.5}],
     {j, 1, NT}], {i, 1, Nmu}];
```

Is it possible to get a density plot similar to the one above?

Comment: What is  deg(e) in the defination of n(x)?

Comment: You haven't given enough information.  The result of your calculation is a value for `x`.  What is `x`? Is that `mu`, so that it's what you're plotting the plot? Then, what are the vlaues of $V_g$ and $T$?  Is that `i` and `j` in that table?  One thing that you should do in the Table is to include the input values, like `gapSol = 
  Table[Table[
    {i, j, x /. FindRoot[gap1[x, Mu[i], T[j]] == 0, {x, 2.5}],
     {j, 1, NT}], {i, 1, Nmu}];`

Comment: @march ```x``` in code is $\Delta$ in latex text. $T$ values are in the code, and $V_g$ is for all intensive purposes same as $\mu$.

Comment: @cvgmt Sorry, it was bad writing on my part that made it unclear, it is the differential. I have edited the definition.

Comment: OK. But now, what is $ \Theta(-x)$ and what is the +1 in  f(x)?

Comment: @cvgmt $\Theta(x)$ is the theta function defined as 0 for $x<0$ and 1 for $x<0$. By 'what is the +1 in f(x)' I think perhaps the question is about the symbol e. It is the exponential function. I have edited the 'e^...'. to be now 'exp(...)'